# How to position content in custom template?

Tags: templates

I have created the index.php and templateDetails.xml file along with css and js and images folders then zipped it all and got it discovered on joomla 3.3.

Trouble is because I added in my index.php html code for the menu and a js slider which works fine with a link to the js and css in the head , the menu and header with slider are at the bottom of the page and I don't know how to position it to the top in my custom template via module manager or by going to menus and trying to place it in position of custom template. There seems to be no option like there is with other templates.

When I click on preview of my custom template it shows basic positions but there is none listed in corresponding elements I've created by just adding the html to my template.

Comment: Don't expect a Joomla workable template, by just adding pieces of html in your template. Have you read anything about Joomla templates first? [Getting Started](http://docs.joomla.org/Getting_Started_with_Templates), [Modifying a Template](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Modifying_a_Joomla!_Template), [Create a basic Template](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you have do! Can you provide your template code?

Comment: I do not just expect to throw in html. I've been trying to follow a tutorial on bootstraps and JUI but I think I might just go back to drupal because changing cms is starting all over, I just thought joomla might be easier for clients.

Comment: But I was hoping to replicate a block menu from html yes, within module manager advanced tab.

Comment: @cea The tutorials you need to follow are those in my first comment

Comment: yes, thanks I had a bit of luck modifying a template today so will persist longer.

Comment: For future questions you might find it helpful to include the code you're working on, that way our community could see whether you're using module positions and visualize your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have added your markup directly to index.php you cannot position it with module manager, as that controls the visibility, content and position of defined modules.

Instead you should add your slider markup as a new custom html module, in module manager, and then assign it to a position in your template. In the case of a menu it would be better to use the menu module, as the content can then be controlled directly from the module manager. Just assign a menu module to the position you want your menu to show in and publish it.